Message source 'replay-channel-listener' on flow 'xxx' found connection error but reconnection is already in progress. Error was: Connection was lost
My mule experience app is having errors in connecting to salesforce as it sends me this error :
Message source 'replay-channel-listener' on flow 'xxx' found connection error but reconnection is already in progress. Error was: Connection was lost

here's my "replay-channel-listener" configuration :
<salesforce:replay-channel-listener streamingChannel="/event/Client_platform_event__e" replayOption="ONLY_NEW" doc:name="Replay channel listener" doc:id="6398d1b0-d3f7-4272-98c0-b252d9975851" config-ref="Salesforce__OAuth_2_0_JWT_Bearer" replayId="-1" cacheEventsInMemory="true" />

Salesforce version is : 10.22.4
has anyone ever encountered this error ? if so have you found a solution ?

It may be a bug in the connector similar to https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=001119590&type=1

I have encountred that solution before, but it specifies upgrading the version, which in my case is on the 10.22.4. but do you think a similar bug could have appeared in this version ? should I downgrade ?

Probably a similar bug since it was fixed in a previous version. Test it if you are willing. Really this is not the place for bugs. Report it to MuleSoft.

Is it not able to reconnect after that? I would hate if this bug reappears in any new version
